# How can I send a "clean" url with retrofit

Tags: android, google-maps, retrofit

I use Retrofit (I'm a beginner) to send a http request to google maps directions api. This is the url I want to send:

> https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin=45.509166,-73.497897&destination=45.5027,-73.503455&waypoints=optimize:false|45.509196,-73.495494|45.511166,-73.493584|45.515887,-73.500751|45.516835,-73.507189|45.514994,-73.515065|45.507828,-73.515879|45.504038,-73.516008|45.508971,-73.505665|&sensor=false

I get a message that says:

> {
>      "error_message" : "Too many waypoints in the request (11). The maximum allowed waypoints for this request is 8, plus the origin, and destination.",
>      "routes" : [],
>      "status" : "MAX_WAYPOINTS_EXCEEDED"
>   }

Which seems normal as an answer, given the fact that when I look in the Logcat (Android studios), the sent url is:

> https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin=origin%3D45.509166%2C-73.497897&destination=destination%3D45.5027%2C-73.503455&waypoints=waypoints%3Doptimize%3Afalse|45.509196%2C-73.495494|45.511166%2C-73.493584|45.515887%2C-73.500751|45.516835%2C-73.507189|45.514994%2C-73.515065|45.507828%2C-73.515879|45.504038%2C-73.516008|45.508971%2C-73.505665|&sensor=sensor%3Dfalse

I guess it has something to do with the headers. Can you please help me to "clean" the url so that I send the first instead of the second one.

Edit: I'll add my code.

Given the fact that I'm using android-priority-jobqueue for my background jobs, and the fact that it is in my background job that I make my http requests, I have to use synch requests with Retrofit, as the blocked thread would be the background job's one.
First of all, the api:

```
    //Retrofit API
    //DirectionApiRequestInterface.java
    public interface DirectionApiRequestInterface {

        @GET("/maps/api/directions/json")
       /*
       //asynch request
        public void getJson(@Query("origin") String origin,
                            @Query("destination") String destination,
                            @Query("waypoints") String waypoints,
                            @Query("sensor") String sensor,
                            //and api key?
                            Callback<String> callback);*/
        //synch request: all wait on the same thread
        public Response getJson(@Query("origin") String origin,
                            @Query("destination") String destination,
                            @Query("waypoints") String waypoints,
                            @Query("sensor") String sensor);

    }
```

Now in my job I have these to make a request:

```
/**
 * Created by Max-poly on 2015-07-14.
 * in this file, we will manage the priorityJobQueue (android-priority-jobqueue from square.)
 * The tasks performed here are:
 * 1- make the Http request
 * 2- parse the response(which we'll try to get in String)
 * 3- calculate the distance between all the points and send the drawn route UI
 */
public class DirectionRequestJob extends Job {
    public static final int PRIORITY = 1;
    private static String baseUrl_ ="https://maps.googleapis.com";
    private static DirectionApiRequestInterface client_;
    private CustomLogger customLogger;

    private ArrayList<String>(); url_;


    /*note that the array list contains the splitted url:
        origin:        url.get(0)
        destination:   url.get(1)
        waypoints:     url.get(2)
        sensor:        url.get(3)
     */
    public DirectionRequestJob(ArrayList<String> url) {
        super(new Params(PRIORITY).requireNetwork().persist());
        url_ = new ArrayList<String>();
        url_.addAll(url);
    }

    //lifecycle of a Job
    @Override
    public void onAdded(){
       //doesn't apply to our case
    }

    @Override
    public void onRun() throws Throwable{
            setupClient();

            // retrofit synch response
            String response = converter(get().getJson(url_.get(0),urls_.get(1),urls_.get(2),urls_.get(3)));

            //parse
            //evaluate the routes/distance/duration etc
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCancel() {
        // Job has exceeded retry attempts or shouldReRunOnThrowable() has returned false.
    }

    @Override
    protected boolean shouldReRunOnThrowable(Throwable throwable) {
        return false;
    }
    //-end lifecyle

    public static DirectionApiRequestInterface get(){
        return client_;
    }

    static{
        setupClient();
    }

    //here is where the rest adapter is setup
    private static void setupClient(){
        RestAdapter.Builder builder = new RestAdapter.Builder()
                .setEndpoint(baseUrl_)
                .setClient(new OkClient(new OkHttpClient()))
                .setLogLevel(RestAdapter.LogLevel.FULL);

        RestAdapter restAdapter = builder.build();
        client_ = restAdapter.create(DirectionApiRequestInterface.class);
    }

    public String converter(Response response){
        return new String(((TypedByteArray) response.getBody()).getBytes());
    }
}
```

As you can see the response returns me the error message above.

Comment: And what does the definition of your Retrofit interface look like?

Comment: It looks like this:
> public Response getJson(@Query("origin") String origin,
                        @Query("destination") String destination,
                        @Query("waypoints") String waypoints,

it is a synch call. Then I use a converter to put the response body in a string. Do you need how I defined my adpter?
                        @Query("sensor") String sensor);

Comment: And what headers are you setting? Do you have complete log of the request? If you don't, use `setLogLevel(LogLevel.FULL)` to get the whole request and response... Maybe that can help...

Comment: @MaximeClaude Can you please post your code ,how you are using retrofit?

Comment: Here I've edited to post the code

Comment: What is the content of your ArrayList<String> url?

Comment: @schopy here is the content : http://postimg.org/image/yxs48u3o7/full/

Comment: @MaximeClaude as I said in the answer, if you put only 45.509166,-73.497897 instead of  origin=45.509166,-73.497897 (and so on for the other items) it should work

Comment: @Schopy, you are right. It works fine now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe in your `url_` items the strings are `origin=the_origin`, `destination=the_destination` and so on. If you leave only the content, what is on the right of `=`, it should work.